# Missing where attribute in the options parameter in Update Function | AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

My service:

```
var values = { progress: userinputs.progress };
var selector = {
    where: { jobId: userinputs.jobId },
};
let newJob = await jobservice.update({ values, selector });
```

jobservice.update:

```
async function update(params) {
    let result = await Job.update(params);
    return result;
}
```

Job Model:

```
const Job = sequelize.define('Job', {
    jobId: {
        type: SEQUELIZE.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: SEQUELIZE.UUIDV4,
    }
    result: {
        type: SEQUELIZE.JSON,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    status: {
        type: SEQUELIZE.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    progress: {
        type: SEQUELIZE.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: '0',
    },
});
```

Error:

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter

How can I fix this? It seems I am passing where attribute properly but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was such a stupid mistake from my side. I had to pass where parameter when I'm calling the actual update function for the job. I passed where clause to the service which was the problem. So simply changing the call function to the code below fixed it.

```
async function update(params) {
    let result = await Job.update(params.values, params.selector);
    return result;
}
```